# rtl8821ce doesn't work on Fedora 36 (5.18.13-200.fc36.x86_64)

Tags: fedora, wifi, drivers

I'm trying to install [rtl8821ce driver](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce)

```
[deavon@liflinty ~]$ cd rtl8821ce
[deavon@liflinty rtl8821ce]$ sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

**OUTPUT**

```
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 already built for kernel 5.18.13-200.fc36.x86_64 (x86_64).
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 already installed on kernel 5.18.13-200.fc36.x86_64 (x86_64).
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

**STILL NOT WORKING** so i check this

```
[deavon@liflinty rtl8821ce]$ nmcli radio all; rfkill list all
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
missing  enabled  missing  enabled 
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

**WHAT?**

EDIT: [image]

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: The wifi, see look something missing.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the procedures described at https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce#readme

**Assuming that you already have this driver installed**, go to the existing directory with the previously installed repository files and perform the steps described in the **"Updating driver"** topic of the README document linked above.